# Difference between EVP_PKEY_RSA and EVP_PKEY_RSA2 in OpenSSL?

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl

What is the difference between the 2 key types in OpenSSL:

1) EVP_PKEY_RSA

2) EVP_PKEY_RSA2

In the library the 2 are defined as:

```
#define EVP_PKEY_RSA    NID_rsaEncryption
#define EVP_PKEY_RSA2   NID_rsa
```

Further, the NIDs are defined as:

```
#define NID_rsaEncryption       6
#define NID_rsa             19
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are EVP_PKEY_RSA type then covers same rsa key pairs, but with different object identifiers used in different contexts, PKCS1 or X509 certificates.

code lines extracted from ***crypto/objects/obj_dat.h***

for EVP_PKEY_RSA    NID_rsaEncryption :

```
0x2A,0x86,0x48,0x86,0xF7,0x0D,0x01,0x01,0x01,/* [ 38] OBJ_rsaEncryption */    
{"rsaEncryption","rsaEncryption",NID_rsaEncryption,9,&(lvalues[38]),0},
```

which is PKCS1 RSA encryption **1.2.840.113549.1.1.1**

for EVP_PKEY_RSA2   NID_rsa

```
0x55,0x08,0x01,0x01,                         /* [104] OBJ_rsa */
{"RSA","rsa",NID_rsa,4,&(lvalues[104]),0},
```

which is rsa encryption for X.500 defined algorithms **id-ea-rsa 2.5.8.1.1**